# Как заставить input выводить значение только из параметра value?

Tags: vue.js, typescript, события, браузер, vue3

У меня есть обычный контролируемый vue компонент, в котором нужно сделать ввод только для чисел. Если же в нем пусто - то должен возвращаться null:

```html
<!-- PriceInput.vue -->
<template>
  <input :value="value" @input="updateValue" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{ value|null: number }>();
defineEmits<{ (e: 'update:value', value: number|null): void }>();

const updateValue = (e) => {
  const price = e.target.value;
  if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(price)) { // если число
    emit('update:value', parseInt(price));
    return;
  }
  if (price == '') {
    emit('update:value', null);
    return;
  }
  // иначе оставляй значение без изменений
  // (например если была введена буква, то она не должна даже появиться в input'е)
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Использование компонента -->
<PriceInput v-model:value="price" />

const price = ref<number|null>(null);
```

Проблема в том, что в случае с вводом не числа и не пустой строки (например "qww123") `emit` не выкидывается (как следствие `value` не меняется) и в компоненте остаётся то значение, которое было введено пользователем.

**Вопрос: как заставить input выводить значение ТОЛЬКО из атрибута `:value`**

Пробовал и `.prevent` и `.stop`, ничего не помогает. Как будто браузер сначала меняет значение input'а при вводе, а только потом создаёт input event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В начале updateValue вставить

```
e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Несмотря на привязку значения `value` к инпуту, после изменений источником правды для него всё равно остаётся значение из event'а. Для решения проблемы можно отправлять emit, для пересчёта value, а потом переписывать этим значением `event.target.value`

```js
const updateValue = (e) => {
  const price = e.target.value;
  if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(price)) {
    emit('update:value', parseInt(price));
  } else if (price == '') {
    emit('update:value', null);
  }
  // Следующая строка решает проблему:
  e.target.value = props.value;
}
```

В общем случае в контролируемом input'е следует обновлять значение так:

```js
const updateValue = (e) => {
  emits('update:value', e.target.value);
  e.target.value = props.value;
};
```